# Laravel geting user role from post model belongsTo relationship

Tags: php, laravel

I have problem to get name from role_user table for each post. I have ACL, so i have 3 tables - users, roles, role_user.

My code looks like this:

Post model

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(user::class);
}
```

User model.

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(post::class);
}
```

Role model.

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->hasmany(user::class);
}
```

PostController,

```
   return view ('admin.posts',[
        'posts' => Post::All()
    ]);
```

In blade I echo fx user name by:

```
  @foreach ($posts as $post)
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">{{$post->id}}</th>
        <td>{{$post->category->name}}</td>
        **<td>{{$post->user->name}}</td>**
      </tr>
  @endforeach
```

But the problem is that i want to echo name of role ( from role_user table) for user who wrote post which i am looping.

**update**

Ok, i solved issue, but probaly there is a better wat. anyone?

I added to models:

User model:

```
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
}
```

And changed role model:

```
public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(user::class);
    }
```

Post controller:

```
class PostController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view ('admin.posts',[
            'posts' => Post::with('user')->get(),
            'roleUsers' => User::with('roles')->get()
        ]);
    }
```

and in blade i am doing

```
  @foreach ($posts as $post)
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">{{$post->id}}</th>
        <td>
          <p>
            @foreach ($roleUsers as $roleUser)
              @foreach($roleUser->roles as $role)
                <p>  
 {{ $role->pivot->user_id === $post->user->id ? "Role: $role->name" : "" }}
                </p>
              @endforeach
            @endforeach
```

I guess there could be a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `withPivot()` method on the relation. Instead of fetching it from the pivot attribute, it will be on the model, if fetched through the many to many relation.

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(user::class)->withPivot();
}
```

Then i would change the front end logic to something in the style of, assuming that all post would have a user with the given role, else you will need to do an if check.

```
@foreach ($roleUsers as $roleUser)
    {{ $roleUser->roles->where('id', $post->user->id)->first()->name }}
@endforeach
```

You question has a lot of code, but this is the way i perceive it and hopefully it can get you closer to better understanding of it.

Comment: Thanks for repaly! It is very helpfull - it will works and it looks better. Just one more thing-  it is ok to use where(),first() etc in blade? I always thought that it will break the rule that there is no direct connection between model and view.

Comment: There is no correct and wrong, i think working with relationships is fair game in blade, have seen it in multiple professional projects. Starting creating objects etc. is where it is a step to much. But most big projects ends up separating front end and backend totally. So blade for me is more for convenience for backend developers and for quick bootstrapping utilizing relationship then is more than fair tbh :)

Comment: Thank's for sharing your experience. It is very good news for me :) My first post was a bit complicated like you said, but your anserws make's me start thinking in a bit different way - problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i fix my problem, thank you for your help. I found many post's similar to my so I will show solution.

Realtion's:
User belongTo post. 
Roles belongsToMany Users.
Users belongsToMany Roles.

DB structure:
users id|User_name
roles id|name
role_user id|user_id|role_id

And what I tried to achieve is while looping through all Post's in blade to display name of role which belongs to that post and solution is very simple.

```
  @foreach ($posts as $post)
      {{$post->user->roles->first()->name}}
  @endforeach
```